# "Maven Test" is not launching the browser for suite run which was working absolutely fine before + Eclipse + Java

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am facing the strange problem, I was able to run the a single Test case and I was able to run the complete suite as well by selecting **Run As --> maven test**. I have not done any changes on my pom but suddenly it stopped working, though i am able to run the scripts one but when I try to run the suite using **maven test** as a run option, project compiles and halts at one place.

Below is the pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ef.sl</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sales_Force_Test_Automation</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                        <!-- <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SalesForce Test</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
                <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

When I run the suite, starts execution but halts at one point before launching the browser

[Click here for the image - console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etQFV.png)

and here is the folder structure of my project :
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5iOc.png)

This is how the failed.xml looks like : 
[Click here for Failed.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHSuf.png)

Though there are related posts here on stackover flow and have tried multiple solutions but none of them resolves the problem that i have encountered. Hoping someone can solve my issue as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hows are you running single tests? Are your test class names ending with *Test.java?

Comment: If you are saying everything was working perfectly fine and you haven't made any changes only one thing I can think of you should try is `Clean` your project and Right Click on project -> Maven -> Update Project or use shortcut alt+F5

Comment: @Sighil : I use to run the single java file [****Test.java] using Testng.

Comment: @Pratik : I have done that before but didnt not help.

Comment: check the target > test-outfput and find the testng xml file generated. See if all the test cases are present there

Comment: @Sighil : I have attached failed.xml on the question above, please check. Even that does not gives the clear picture why the complete suite run is not happening and single test case run is working fine !

Comment: There is no apparent issues there! Would have to see the test case structure and driver invocation code

Comment: @Sighil : This is really weird because everything was working smoothly and suddenly stopped working without no reason. And it is affected only on suite run.
Single test cases are executing normally

Comment: Have you tried creating a testng XML suite file and trigger it via maven. I can see that in the pom file the location of testng file is commented out

Comment: @Sighil did try it but there was some issue with path. since then i have not been working on it. 

So basically my testNG file path is : **C:\Prateek\Project\SFAutomation\src\test\resources\testng.xml**  and i had tried giving it like 
** <!-- <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
** but it didnt work.